# JAVA initialize AtomicIntegerArray

Tags: java

I'm wondering why it doesn't work to initialize an AtomicIntegerArray like this:

```
AtomicIntegerArray atomarr = new AtomicIntegerArray(100);
```

Eclipse marks that line as an error *Syntax error on token ";", , expected*

According to the JAVA API which states:

> public AtomicIntegerArray(int length)
>
> Creates a new AtomicIntegerArray of the given length, with all
>   elements initially zero.
>
> Parameters:
>   length - the length of the array

So it should work like that for my understanding.

I did find a work-around though:

```
AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger;
size.set(100);
AtomicIntegerArray atomarr = new AtomicIntegerArray(size);
```

Does this mean the Integer for the size of the Array is obliged to be an AtomicInteger aswell?

Comment: When you say AtomicIntegerArray atomarr = new AtomicIntegerArray(100); does not work, what error do you see?

Comment: The problem must be with another line, the one you posted works fine. Please post some more code.

Comment: Got it. As soon as one starts bothering other people with syntax errors, one finds it. Classic.
Cheers mate, once again, sorry. ;)